# jQuery to store data for sessions

Tags: jquery, memory, session, caching, store

I am trying to use jQuery AJAX. What my requirement is, i wish to load user names from DB in dataset, convert it to JSON format and store it in memory or using jQuery data for use while a user is browsing my site, i.e for a session. This way I can use autocomplete or my own code to display data to user.

Can anyone help me design such a scenario?

Comment: How do you interact with your database?... what language?

Comment: Its a Sql db with c# as the language

Comment: If you're using C# then you can just use the Autocomplete extender. Why beat yourself up to do something difficult? ~ Alternatively, are you trying to have it be faster on the server or the client? Either the question is poorly worded or you're missing something. Can you give any more clarification?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### HTML 5 Web Storage

*think beyond cookies, Google Gears and proprietary solutions*

Standardized, no special plugin required. Scriptable through JavaScript/jQuery. Although supported only in the latest browsers, you can use [HTML 5 Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/), namely *localStorage* and *sessionStorage* properties, intended to keep state on the client side in context of the website between page requests. Holds a heck of a lot more than cookies. For example [IE 8 DOM storage spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062(v=VS.85).aspx) (10 MB client-side storage), [Firefox DOM storage spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage).

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [YUI 2 Storage Utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/storage/) which abstracts the storage for you (HTML 5, Google Gears, SWF) depending on what the browser supports:

> The Storage Utility provides a
>   mechanism for storing significant
>   amounts of textual data, client-side,
>   whether or not your browsers supports
>   the proposed HTML 5 Storage
>   specification.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery data may not be useful because you will lose the data when you go from one page to the next as the page is refreshed, you can however do this using COOKIES -- there is a [jQuery cookies plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookies) that will make it easier for you.

Comment: If the list is very long, the user will be sending that cookie to the server every. single. request. That could cause Hell for your request headers buffers on your server. If the list is smaller than 8k, it should work, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions means serverside. jQuery means clientside. You can't translate between the two. Cookies is the best you can hope for to remain strictly clientside.

Comment: By sessions means that I could store my data from db in some memory which could be searchable via jQuery as a datastore. It could be anything like an jscript array or even jQuery.data(). Just that I do not want my data to be fetched everytime from db.

Comment: You can avoid hitting the DB with memcached or writing the JSON to a file.

Comment: Cookies is second best. Better than cookies on client side, although not as widely supported (i.e. older browsers) is HTML 5 Web Storage: http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/

Comment: @jdk - if HTML5 were in widespread use, I would say target that. @Ted you cant get to the session if you're on the client. End of story. You have to send it to the client. That means per page, which includes postback to sync the two. At that point, it is neither session nor cookie, just data on a form (form being a generic method of storing data in a browser pane).

Answer (score 0):

[Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/) is the only solution I know of for doing this, but it requires the user to install it and only runs on a few browsers. You could, however, use `$.getJSON` to fetch a list of users, JSON-encoded and gzipped, from your server when the user say... focuses the auto-completed search box, then use aggressive client-side resource caching to reduce the number of hits on your database.

If it's a pretty long list of users, you may want to look into using memcached to store the list, or perhaps writing it to a file and having it be served directly by your front-end server (i.e. Nginx, Lighttpd, Apache: pretty much anything that avoids running a DB query)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557) with great success to do pretty much what you're describing.  It's a lightweight plugin (< 10k) that abstracts away client-side storage using any of these available backends:

- flash: Flash 8 persistent storage.
- gears: Google Gears-based persistent storage.
- localstorage: HTML5 draft storage.
- whatwg_db: HTML5 draft database storage.
- globalstorage: HTML5 draft storage (old spec).
- ie: Internet Explorer userdata behaviors.
- cookie: Cookie-based persistent storage.

It transparently picks the best storage backend based on browser capability and installed plugins.  It works with:

- globalStorage: Firefox 2.0+, Internet Explorer 8
- localStorage: development WebKit
- openDatabase: Safari 3.1+
- userdata behavior: Internet Explorer 5.5+

...and optionally falls back to cookies if none of the other persistent storage options work.  The DOM storage methods get you at least a few megabytes worth of storage space; you'll be limited to roughly 4kB if you fall back to cookies.